# Why does Visual Studio 2019 freeze when I call Trace.WriteLine with a long string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, freeze

In the codebase I'm working on, I have a method that looks like this:

```cs
        private void ClientMqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
            Trace.WriteLine($"client_MqttMsgPublishReceived topic: {e.Topic} {msg}");

            TaskCompletionSourceResponse.TrySetResult(msg);
        }
```

The issue is the following call:

```cs
Trace.WriteLine($"client_MqttMsgPublishReceived topic: {e.Topic} {msg}");
```

`e.Message` is a JSON object encoded as a byte array containing 2,669,000 bytes. It gets converted to a string `msg` of the same number of characters. Next, `Trace.WriteLine()` is called with an interpolated string as its argument, which contains the string `msg`. This call to `Trace.WriteLine()` causes Visual Studio 2019 to freeze for about a minute, making it completely unresponsive:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 freeze]

The simplest solution seems to be to simply delete the call to `Trace.WriteLine()`. However, I am still interested in knowing why Visual Studio stops responding? And if there's another way to mitigate this issue? Can't `Trace.WriteLine()` handle too long strings?

Comment: Why do you need such long string in trace? Maybe just write it to the log file? Does debugger shows it correctly?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The string is correctly shown in the debug output window in Visual Studio. I don't need it, the code just looked like this when I started working on it. And I wonder why Visual Studio behaves like this in this case.

Comment: If the string is being displayed in VS (eg. locals window) this can be slow with very long strings.